# How to handle fetching data with an auth-token in a server component, version 13.5?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, next.js13, react-server-components

I have a client-side login that returns a token. Now, I want to create another server-side page to fetch some data, but I don't understand how to set the token on the server side for use in my fetch.
I use next 13.5 apollo client

I have a customHook to get token and set to localstorage because i have another pages client side
I use this hook into the login

```
const useGetToken = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const router = useRouter()
    const {
        data,
        loading,
        error,
        refetch
    } = useQuery<GetUserJWTResponse>(GET_USER_JWT, {
        variables: { userEmail: email },
        notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
        skip: !email,
    });


    useEffect(() => {
        if (data?.getUserJWT?.data) {
            localStorage.setItem('token', data?.getUserJWT?.data)
            router.push('/company')
        }
    }, [data]);



    return {
        setEmail
    }
}

export default useGetToken
```

```
import { GET_USER } from "@/graphql/queries"
import { getClient } from "@/lib/client"


server component where i need add token
export default async function Profile({ params }: { params: { profileId: string } }) {

    const { data } = await getClient().query({
        query: GET_USER,
        variables: { userId: params.profileId },
        context: {
            next: {
                revalidate: 60000
            }
        }

    })
    console.log(" ~ file: page.tsx:6 ~ Profile ~ data:", data)

    return (
        <div>
            something
        </div>
    )
}
```

I need set token server side

Comment: Your question needs further refinement.

First, explain the necessity for the token on both the client and the server.

Then, consider if you can have only the server side obtain the token, act on the received data and communicate such data to your client.

Making an authentication token flow from the client to the server may not be the best solution for your problem.